# MySQL: Select 2 earliest times (AM) ever recorded

Tags: php, mysql

In my sample table is there some way to find out what the first 2 earliest times ever recorded is? I'm not after the earliest row recorded but the earliest based on H:i:s (not Y-m-d). In this case it would be **row 3** and **row 4** since it has a time of 4:07AM and 5:08AM, respectively, regardless of the date.

```
id     first_name       time 
1       joe             2011-10-01 10:01:00
2       mary            2011-10-02 06:05:00
3       sam             2011-10-03 04:07:00
4       mel             2011-10-04 05:08:00
5       bo              2011-10-05 13:10:00
```

Comment: Do you only want times between midnight and noon?

Answer (score 2):

You need to extract the time component from the date/time field (confusingly called "time").  Fortunately, MySQL has a function for this:

```
select time(`time`)
from t
order by time(`time`)
limit 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers take a look at the whole DATETIME column, if you want the earliest time (H:m:s) you will need to run a [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
SELECT time FROM table ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(time, '%H:%m:%s') ASC LIMIT 2;
```

You can also use [`TIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time) instead: `ORDER BY TIME(time) ASC`. If you want to select the time (without a PHP function) you can use `SELECT TIME(time) as time`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select time from table order by time(time) asc limit 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers with `ORDER BY TIME(time)` will fulfil your requirement and it's good if your requirement doesn't have to scale.

My MySQL `explain`s me that it has to sort all rows for this query. If efficiency is a concern for you, you have to split your *time* row into two rows, *date* and *timeonly*. With an index on *timeonly*, there's no need to look at all rows.